# How to properly use the for-range statements syntax in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, language-lawyer

```
iteration-statement:
    while ( condition ) statement
    do statement while ( expression ) ;
    for ( init-statement conditionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
    for ( init-statementopt for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
for-range-declaration:
    attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator
    attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifieropt [ identifier-list ]
for-range-initializer:
    expr-or-braced-init-list
```

The syntax above is given by C++ISO. I have seen a ton of examples using the classic approach for a for-range statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    for (int i : a) { cout << i << endl; }
}
```

But I'm not finding how to use `for-range-declaration` as `attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifieropt [ identifier-list ]`. How does it work in this case? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Something like `for (const auto& element : a) ...`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, I think `[identifier-list]` is for structured bindings, like `for (auto [i,j] : v)`. The multiple declarations in your example should be part of `init-statementopt`, right?

Comment: Oh yeah, it support structured bindings.  I keep forgetting about those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the grammar

```
attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifieropt [ identifier-list ]
```

is to allow for structured bindings in a loop. e.g. you could do something like this:

```
struct S { int i,j; };
std::vector<S> v;
for (auto [a, b] : v)
  // ... a and b simply refer to i and j
```

Note that the `identifier-list` indicates that the names `a` and `b` just refer to the members of the struct.

Comment: What about `expr-or-braced-init-list`? I dived into the syntax of this expression, but it was kinda deep. What coud it be in the case of using the `[identifier list]`?

Comment: @Roman The `expr-or-braced-init-list` in the answer is `v`. You could also make a braced-init-list like this `S x,y,z; for (auto [a,b] : {x,y,z}) // ...`